# Why creating variable when calling function is slower than create variable and pass it to function?

Tags: c++, performance

I create a variable and after definition i use the variable name for function arguments, which is faster than immediately create variable in function call arguments.

For example i run this 5 times:

```cpp
int  main()
{
  std::vector<some>             vector;
  boost::timer::auto_cpu_timer  _;

  for (size_t i = 0; i < std::numeric_limits<uint16_t>::max(); ++i)
  {
    some  value;
    vector.push_back(value);
  }
}
```

And got :

```sh
 0.012644s wall, 0.000000s user + 0.000000s system = 0.000000s CPU (n/a%)
 0.012056s wall, 0.000000s user + 0.000000s system = 0.000000s CPU (n/a%)
 0.011773s wall, 0.000000s user + 0.010000s system = 0.010000s CPU (84.9%)
 0.011925s wall, 0.000000s user + 0.000000s system = 0.000000s CPU (n/a%)
 0.011949s wall, 0.010000s user + 0.000000s system = 0.010000s CPU (83.7%)
```

But this code :

```cpp
int  main()
{
  std::vector<some>             vector;
  boost::timer::auto_cpu_timer  _;

  for (size_t i = 0; i < std::numeric_limits<uint16_t>::max(); ++i)
  {
    vector.push_back(some { });
  }
}
```

Give me :

```sh
 0.013350s wall, 0.000000s user + 0.000000s system = 0.000000s CPU (n/a%)
 0.013896s wall, 0.010000s user + 0.000000s system = 0.010000s CPU (72.0%)
 0.013314s wall, 0.010000s user + 0.000000s system = 0.010000s CPU (75.1%)
 0.015149s wall, 0.000000s user + 0.000000s system = 0.000000s CPU (n/a%)
 0.012713s wall, 0.000000s user + 0.000000s system = 0.000000s CPU (n/a%)
```

Which is slower than creating variable and then pass it to function. Why ? what is difference ?

---

**NOTE:** The `some` structure is :

```cpp
struct some
{
  std::string  name, family;
  uint16_t     age;

  struct
  {
    std::string  another_one;
    uint16_t     another_one_age;
  }  some_time;
};
```

**NOTE:** I don't use any special compiler flag for compiling those programs.

Comment: The wall time is going to be less reliable, since you could get bit just by regular cpu scheduling.  Run a profiler and see which is doing more work.

Comment: *I don't use any special compiler flag for compiling those programs.* -- Then the timings are meaningless.  You should be testing optimized code.  Turn on the optimization flags and retest.

Comment: @StephenNewell, I use [Hotspot](https://github.com/KDAB/hotspot) but i don't understand the output graphs.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, Okay i will try it.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, I use `-O3` and both is same.

Comment: @Anthony, Have you tried moving value? `vector.push_back(std::move(value));`

Comment: @JohnPark, No,  I think compiler automatically move it.

Comment: The difference is pushing back an lvalue compared to an rvalue. Copying versus moving. [`push_back`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back) have different overload for each.

Comment: And please check the generated assembly code to see what the compiler *really* do.

Comment: How about `vector.emplace_back()` ?

Comment: And what about `some  value;` being moved out of the `for` loop (in the first case)?

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili, In my program i use `push_back` and i wanted to measurement it. And my structure is complex and i can't send parameters Immediately.

Comment: @RickJames, I tried but it doesn't change anything (in measurement).

Comment: If you can't send the arguments immediately, `push_back(some{})` makes no sense to me since it's effectively `emplace_back()`.

Answer (score 0):

I'll bet there is a function that will create a `vector` of N `some`.  That is likely to be a lot faster than your `for` loop.

Comment: Sorry, i don't understand  what you mean.